# hide a transparent text on input double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't want the user to see the text entered in an input, I have already used `color: transparent` and the text is hidden but when the user double clicks on the input, the text becomes visible! How can I hide it when input is selected via double click.
thanks in advance.

```css
#loginCard{
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="loginCard">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use input type =password

Comment: Add you code into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add

```
::selection {
  background: transparent;
}
```

For firefox:

```
::-moz-selection {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in CSS to change the text marking highlight color

N.B: You can also use `transparent` in color. I use white as the background is white. But using `transparent` will be wiser.

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

```css
::selection {
  background: #fff; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #fff; /* Gecko Browsers */
}

.sample {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="sample" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this but you can use css:

```
input, textarea { 
-webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
 -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome and Opera */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
input::selection {
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
}
```

would make it transparent

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::selection` set to `transparent`

[Support](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aselection)

```css
input {
  color: transparent;
}

input::selection {
 color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<input type="password" id="password" >
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#password').dblclick(function(){
     $('#password').attr("type","text");
    })

});
```